# 8086 segment selector

Tags: x86, x86-16, memory-segmentation

Is there some "supervisor" bit to not let the "user space" do something like

```
mov CS, 200h
```

What kind of protection is there?

Comment: Protection?  On the 8086?  Are you kidding?

Comment: The 8086 may mean "x86-class" rather than the specific 8086 CPU. I base that on the fact that I don't think they were even _called_ selectors until the 386 (286?) came in. Before that, they were just segment _registers._

Comment: I actually mean 8086, not x86. But its a good observation, they are not selectors because at that time they weren't indexes on descriptor tables.

Comment: If you mean the actual 8086 then no, no protections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the *actual* 8086 CPU? No. The advanced protection features only really started appearing with the 80286. There were no restrictions on what programs could set the code segment to on the 8086.

With segment registers (in real mode), there were no protections or virtual memory, and the physical address was calculated by a simple shift and add. For example, `1234:5678` referred to physical address `179B8` as per:

```
12340
 5678 +
-----
179B8
```

In protected mode, the values in `CS` (and `DS`, `ES`, and so on) changed from segment registers to *selectors* and they had to have entries in a descriptor table (eg, the global `GDT` or local `LDT`).

The selector was used to look up an entry in the relevant table and retrieve things like base address, size, protections, and so on.

I don't think it was the *loading* into a selector register that caused the violations. Rather it was the *use* of a selector above your privilege level (or other things, like trying to access memory beyond the end of the block).

For CS, that would happen pretty quickly after you changed it (as you tried to execute the next instruction). Other registers may take longer to fault because you may not use them straight away.

---

Just keep in mind that an instruction like `mov cs, 200h`, even if it *existed*, would be a rather strange way to effect a `jmp` (as would *any* instruction that changed `cs` independently of `ip`).

It would require you to ensure the code you wanted to transfer control to had a *very* specific offset in the memory referenced by the target selector since `ip` would not be changed by that instruction (beyond the normal small increment that normally happens with sequential execution, of course).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I asked this because I saw somewhere that that instruction was invalid under certain circumstances, but I'm wasn't sure that was correct.

Comment: The instruction `mov CS, imm` is invalid simply because it does not exist. Only `mov CS, ax` exists.

Comment: @ruslik: I don't believe `mov cs, ax` is a legal instruction and, in fact, it makes little sense to set `cs` independent of `ip`. Though `debug` allows you to enter it and it seems to disassemble okay, it does *not* act as you would expect. There's also lots of doco stating that `mov` can't be used with `cs` as a target so I suspect that's just a limitation of `debug`.